# How to get the values by association in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have three tables,

```
Alpha - :set_code, :field_code 

Beta - :set_code, :field_code # both fields are primary key in BETA table

Gamma - :field_code, :field_name
```

I have three Classes in my model:

```
Class Alpha
  belongs_to :alpha_beta, foreign_key: 'set_code', class_name: 'Beta'
end

Class Beta
  belongs_to :beta_gamma, foreign_key: 'field_code', class_name: 'Gamma'
end

Class Gamma
end
```

In my Alpha view, I want to display the `field_name` in the `drop down box` by the selected `params` and give the option to change and update the `field_name`.

I tried like the following upto `Beta` table and I don't have any idea of how to getting the value from `Gamma` by using the `Beta` Class.

```
<%= f.select :field_code, Beta.all.map{|b| [b.field_Code, b.set_code]} %>
```

Note: the `field_name` should come under where `alpha` table `:set_code` = `beta` table `:set_code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<%= f.select :set_code, Beta.all.map {|b| [b.beta_gamma.field_name, b.set_code] } %>
```

You can access the associated records through the `belongs_to` relationship.

```
alpha = Alpha.first
alpha.alpha_beta #=> instance of Beta
alpha.alpah_beta.beta_gamma #=> instance of Gamma
```